# Why setter method not setting Value in handleMessage method?

Tags: android, handler, mutablelivedata

my code:

```
private MutableLiveData<String> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg){
String s = (String) msg.obj;
liveData.setValue(s);
}
}
```

But when `getLiveData()` called, no value returned. I checked with Log value of `s`, it has a string value, which I want to set. But not setting in liveData. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the  `super.handleMessage(s)` method. This fix the issue.